# NLB or direct connection to the mailserver on EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, nlb, aws-nlb

I'm running simple Postfix server **only** for receiving emails. Postfix is in Docker container next to the other microservices on the EC2 instance. This email service is the only one that is open to the world on the port 25 (MX record, DNS record) directly to the IP address.

Is it safe to have it next to the other (private) services? Is it better to create Network Load Balancer instead of directly connect to the IP address? Is it better to have "public" services on separated machine?

Comment: IMO AWS SES is priced low enough that it's not worth the effort to manually setting up a MTA unless email sending is the core part of your business.

Comment: Yes, I've already tried SES receive and Lambda to process my emails, but it doesn't support attachements. So I have to save it to the s3 bucket, invoke sns which invokes lambda function. It's overkill for my usrcase when you compare to with one simple postfix container.